# Couldn't parse stream - CXF Issue

Tags: cxf, cxf-client

I am receiving below CXF exception while receiving supplier response. I am using apache cxf 2.7.18 version. Not able to identify the issue. Please help to resolve the issue. Please find below stack-trace for details also attaching exception screenshot

```
[http-bio-6099-exec-48] WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Interceptor for {http://www.travelport.com/service/universal_v41_0}AirService#{http://www.travelport.com/service/universal_v41_0}service has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't parse stream.
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1705)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:123)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:849)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1642)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1520)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1317)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:223)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy72.service(Unknown Source)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.vendorapi.galileouapi.WrapGalileouapiAirServiceImpl.bookGalileoUAPILCC(WrapGalileouapiAirServiceImpl.java:364)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.vendorapi.galileouapi.WrapGalileouapiAirServiceImpl.doBooking(WrapGalileouapiAirServiceImpl.java:268)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.productimpl.WrapAirBlackboxControlUnit.bookAir(WrapAirBlackboxControlUnit.java:822)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.WrapBlackBoxProductBookControlEngine.bookAirProduct(WrapBlackBoxProductBookControlEngine.java:237)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.WrapBlackboxControlEngine.doBooking(WrapBlackboxControlEngine.java:419)
        at com.vtech.appxtension.tdpms.blackbox.WrapBlackboxControlEngine.processRequestXml(WrapBlackboxControlEngine.java:79)
        at com.vtech.webservice.WebServiceSearchBookServlet.doPost(WebServiceSearchBookServlet.java:187)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: stream is closed
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:550)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:605)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createSR(WstxInputFactory.java:628)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(WstxInputFactory.java:331)
        at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.StaxUtils.createXMLStreamReader(StaxUtils.java:1703)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: stream is closed
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.ensureOpen(ChunkedInputStream.java:174)
        at sun.net.www.http.ChunkedInputStream.read(ChunkedInputStream.java:673)
        at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3066)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.BaseReader.readBytes(BaseReader.java:155)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ISOLatinReader.read(ISOLatinReader.java:83)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.initialLoad(ReaderBootstrapper.java:250)
        at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderBootstrapper.bootstrapInput(ReaderBootstrapper.java:133)
        at com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory.doCreateSR(WstxInputFactory.java:545)
```

I am using CXF version 2.7.18 [image: Stack-trace]

Comment: Please post your code